# OpenVPN tun0 extremely slow

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm working in a vpn - the server is connected via a 16.000 mb/s line. Sure, this connection is really slow itself, but the vpn connection doesn't use the real bandwith.

So i connected to the server and run nmon to watch the network stats. I tried to download a 10MB file from the vpn server. Then is saw, that eth0 on the server uses full upload bandwidth (100kb/s), but tun0 uses maximum 10kb/s.

The client also has a download of only 10kb/s. Why does tun0 not use the full upload bandwith of eth0?

**EDIT:** Guys, I even realized that the tun0 connection isn't that slow all time.. I should mention that i'm using a CIFS share via the openvpn and the problem is only on directory browsing through CIFS. If I download a file via http request or so the upload speed on tun0 is 100kb/s indeed. Is there any way to improve the performance of directory browsing via openvpn?

Comment: If `eth0` is using the full upload bandwidth, then how can any more data be pushed over the connection? Also, keep in mind that VPN can also be limited by CPU speed (encryption is *not* free or cheap), and that encryption also increases the size of data by about 1/3.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is only on directory browsing through CIFS.

This is just how CIFS/SMB is if you are on a high latency connection (>~50ms).  You can see some improvement if your client is running Winodws Vista or above, and the server are running Windows Server 2008 R2 or above.  This is because newer versions of Windows have updated versions of the SMB protocols which reduce the effects of latency.  Though it still isn't completely eliminated.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#WAN_performance_issues
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/neilcar/archive/2004/10/26/247903.aspx

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/a/316611/984

Answer (score 0):

There are two considerations to keep in mind, when trying to evaluate the effectiveness of a connection.

The first one is that you might not be the sole user of the connections, in which case you would be entitled to  smaller fraction of the total bandwidth than you think you deserve. Keep in mind that all sorts of traffic are generated by a LAN, including requests of updates for pcs and firmwares, surfing traffic, and so on.

The second consideration is that the traffic the user of the VPN generates needs to be encrypted, and this consumes time. I do not know which kind of computing power you have at your disposal, but just remember that in these things the connection is only as fast as it *slowest* component.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm the only user of the bandwith. The server at my home-office and i'm accessing to it from another office. I even realized, that the performance isn't that slow all the time, just on directory browsing. The server uses a quad core processor (don't know the exact model) and 4GB of ram - should be enough for some encryption, doesn't it? :/

Comment: @chris.ribal Yes, it's plenty. Then you will have to give us more info. When is it slow, and is it not?